# How do I resolve 'Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has no builders defined' error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am writing an ionic Angular app, and recently cloned the repo to another machine.

Next I did an `npm install` then an `ionic serve` which results in the following error:

> $ ionic serve
>   ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
>   [ng] An unhandled exception occurred: **Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has no builders defined**.
>   [ng] See "C:\Users\wadef\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-NUA28c\angular-errors.log" for further details.

The error log has the following:

> [error] Error: Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has no builders
>   defined.
>       at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (C:\code\powercut\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:46:19)
>   at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (C:\code\powercut\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:175:55)
>   at async RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (C:\code\powercut\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:217:24)

I've tried:

- deleting `package-lock.json` and doing a fresh `npm install`
- specifically reinstalling `@angular-devkit/build-angular`
- searching for the error message, but I cannot find a single reference to it

Comment: probably your angular.json is not correctly configured

Comment: Do you have the Ionic CLI installed globally on the machine you're using?

Comment: @R.Richards yes, along with the Angular CLI

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new blank ionic project so I could compare angular.json as prompted by Poul's comment. I got a bunch of different errors which lead me to do the following:

```
<added NODE_PATH environment variable>
npm install -g npm
npm cache verify
<delete package-lock.json>
npm install
```

The error no longer occurs.